# hadoop fs -text vs hadoop fs -cat vs hadoop fs -get

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

I believe all the following commands can be used for copying the hdfs files to local file system. What are the differences / situational pro/cons. ( Hadoop newbie here ).

```
hadoop fs -text /hdfs_dir/* >> /local_dir/localfile.txt
hadoop fs -cat /hdfs_dir/* >> /local_dir/localfile.txt
hadoop fs -get /hdfs_dir/* >> /local_dir/
```

My thumb-rule is to avoid using 'text' and 'cat' for big files. ( I use it to copy output of my MR job which is usually smaller in my use case ).

Comment: -text will only work with zip and TextRecordInputStream formats.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference between -cat and -text is that text detects the encoding of the file and decodes it to plain text whenever possible whereas cat doesnt do it.

for eg take the example of this lzo compressed file.

using text:

```
hadoop fs -text hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse/database/000000_0.lzo_deflate
1,foo
2,bar
3,baz
4,hello
5,world
```

using cat:

```
 hadoop fs -cat hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse/database/000000_0.lzo_deflate 
    ίiW3�I���2�IJ,�2�U\&:�99�\�:��E9)\֙��"
```

dfs -get command is used to copy files to local-filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop fs -get 
hadoop fs -copyToLocal
```

Above HDFS commands can be used for copying the HDFS files to local system.

```
hadoop fs -cat
```

This command will display the content of the  HDFS file on your stdout (console or command prompt).

```
hadoop fs  -text
```

This will display the content of the hdfs file ( But text  only work with zip and TextRecordInputStream formats like SequenceFieFormat).

Comment: it works for others too but you have to provide the libraries relevant to your encryption mechanism

Answer (score 0):

-text

> Usage: hadoop fs -text   Takes a source file and outputs the file
>   in text format. The allowed formats are zip and TextRecordInputStream.

-cat

> Usage: hadoop fs -cat URI [URI …] Copies source paths to stdout.

-get

> Usage: hadoop fs -get [-ignorecrc] [-crc]    Copy files
>   to the local file system. Files that fail the CRC check may be copied
>   with the -ignorecrc option. Files and CRCs may be copied using the
>   -crc option.